# Not able to load json file from server using get post angular

Tags: angularjs, api

Hey I'm trying to use $http get function from angular to retrieve a json file from server located at **"http://localhost/week10/resources/dog.json"** 
But I can't seem to access the file. The code works fine when I use the file in the local destination.

My code looks like this

This is the angular file responsible for getting data

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost/week10/resources/dog.json"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.dogObj = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.dogObj = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

The code for displaying these characters

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="x in dogObj">

            <div class="thumbnail">
             <a href="view/view2/{{x.actual_name}}"> <img src="{{x.src}}" ></a>
            </div>

     </li>
</ul>
```

And the json looks like this

```
[{"actual_name":"dog1.htm","shown_name":"dog1","src":"images/dog1.jpg"},
                          {"actual_name":"dog2.htm","shown_name":"dog2","src":"images/dog2.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog3.htm","shown_name":"dog3","src":"images/dog3.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog7.htm","shown_name":"dog7","src":"images/dog7.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog4.htm","shown_name":"dog4","src":"images/dog4.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog5.htm","shown_name":"dog5","src":"images/dog5.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog6.htm","shown_name":"dog6","src":"images/dog6.jpg"},
                           {"actual_name":"dog8.htm","shown_name":"dog8","src":"images/dog8.jpg"}]
```

The code works file when I change the 
**url:dog.json** as there is a dog file in a local destination as well

but when I change it to **http://localhost/week10/resources/dog.json** The site doesn't work.

If I simply put the file into the browser the json file shows up.

The browser inspect console shows xml parsing error.

Comment: Cross site scripting issue?  I had to install a CORS enabling extension for chrome to access REST services coming from "elsewhere" - localhost on a different port, or a totally different machine.  Try console.log()-ing the file when it arrives in your fetch handler

Comment: hey ivanivan could you please give me an example

Comment: Please post the exact error message. Look at the network tab of the Developer Console to see if the headers are correct. There should not be an XML parse error because the content-type should be `application/json`.

Comment: It says accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Comment: In chrome the debugger will throw you an error message about it if that is your issue.  You could also add in a `console.log()` call that spits out part of a record right after your `$scope.dogObj=response.data;` statement

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it is your issue, but sometime what you get from the server is not json although you might think it should be. I did this to set up my headers. Only because register answered with text and login answered with json.

```
const registerHttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }),
  responseType: "text" as "json"
};

const loginHttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
};
```

I also advise to learn to use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) to see what actual response from the server you are getting and in what format.
I assume you already checked F12/Network/Headers, F12/Network/Response Payload.

Interesting read on header setup in [Angular Git repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586)